# In Matlab, why does square of L2 Norm of whole matrix does not matches to sum of square of row/column wise L2 Norm?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, precision, norm

Square of L2-Norm of matrix should match to Sum of square of all rows/columns L2-Norm.
Reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html

Consider following random (4,3) matrix in Matlab

```
Computed using a = rand(4,3)

0.0400    0.4357    0.9144
0.5551    0.9048    0.5755
0.1675    0.1772    0.3001
0.4189    0.0403    0.2407
```

L2 Norm of whole matrix is:

```
norm(a1)^2 = 2.7806
```

L2 Norm of Sum of square of columns:

```
norm(a1(:,1))^2 + norm(a1(:,2))^2 + norm(a1(:,3))^2 = 2.9337
```

L2 Norm of Sum of square of rows:

```
norm(a1(1,:))^2 + norm(a1(2,:))^2 + norm(a1(3,:))^2 = 2.2214
```

Where as, this matches in Python (numpy):

```
a = np.random.rand(4,3)
array([[ 0.91033221,  0.9082118 ,  0.6864961 ],
   [ 0.15157616,  0.70232112,  0.06709103],
   [ 0.61008197,  0.15648347,  0.02693866],
   [ 0.53646277,  0.22186601,  0.77530143]])
```

L2 Norm of whole matrix

```
numpy.linalg.norm(a)**2 = 3.9810836846898465
```

L2 Norm Sum of square of rows:

```
numpy.linalg.norm(a[0])**2  + numpy.linalg.norm(a[1])**2  + 
numpy.linalg.norm(a[2])**2 + numpy.linalg.norm(a[3])**2 = 3.9810836846898465
```

Is Matlab not doing operation at higher precision which cumilatively adding up the difference in the Whole Matrix Norm and Row-Column wise?

Is there any option in Matlab which allows me do this correcly?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33083/what-is-the-difference-between-the-frobenius-norm-and-the-2-norm-of-a-matrix) I found a nice answer about the different L2 norms. Quote: Element-wise norm: which is like unwrapping A into a long vector, then calculating its vector norm. Schatten norm: which measures the vector norm of the singular values of A. There is one more called the induced norm which seems to be the matlab norm(A,2).

Comment: You are missing one row from your calculations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab uses a different norm for matrices than vectors. From the Matlab Doc for `norm`:

> n = norm(X) returns the 2-norm or maximum singular value of matrix X, which is approximately max(svd(X)).

So to get a similar result to your row- and columnwise calculations you must vectorize the matrix.

```
M =[0.0400, 0.4357, 0.9144;
    0.5551, 0.9048, 0.5755;
    0.1675, 0.1772, 0.3001;
    0.4189, 0.0403, 0.2407 ];

norms = [];
norms(end+1) = norm(M)^2;    % 2.46
norms(end+1) = norm(M(:))^2; % 2.87
norms(end+1) = norm(M(1,:))^2 + norm(M(2,:))^2 + norm(M(3,:))^2 + norm(M(4,:))^2; % 2.87
norms(end+1) = norm(M(:,1))^2 + norm(M(:,2))^2 + norm(M(:,3))^2; % 2.87

norms
```